# React Native no internet fetch crashes

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `React Native` with `Redux` for an chat android app.

In my application I have an action which fetch the api like this:

```
this.props.actions.getMessages(someID)
```

This will be called in the chat component lifecycle `componentDidMount()`.

Also In my app in the root container I check if I have internet connection, if not I show a modal above everything.

My problem is like this: if the chat component mounts and I lose my internet connection then app crash.

I'm doing something wrong? How can I stop fetch if I dont have no internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check the connection everytime it goes off and on where you call getMessages.
With this snippet you can check when the connection goes on and off:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const dispatchConnected = isConnected => this.props.dispatch(setIsConnected(isConnected));

  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then().done(() => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', dispatchConnected);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I'm doing this but for example sometimes I go to chat page and before the fetch is successfull I disable the internet connection, then instead showing the offline page its crashing..

Comment: Why not save the value of the connection check in a state and pass it to the pages you need? Then in the render with an if/else show the page you want?

Comment: I'm saving, i have isConnected in auth reducer, but my problem is that the user lost connection in the middle of fetching the data the app crashes. In more simple words User has connection -> User request -> Fetch is unfinished -> User lost connection -> Crash

Comment: To fetch API I use axios, because native `fetch()` on Android keeps crashing the app. You can use a `.catch()` to show what you need in case of fail.

Comment: This one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios
Thank you for the 'accept'